# trying out priority queues and my offer method isn't putting items at the end

Tags: java

My program works fine until i poll out a few items and then add in, at times my offer method puts an item in the front of the queue instead of the back. I've added in a few print statements so one can see what is happening in the queue.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PriorityQ {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      PriorityQueue<String> q = new PriorityQueue<String>();
      String input = "";
      while (!input.equals("X")) {
         input = s.nextLine();
         if (input.equals("O") && q.peek() == null) {
            System.out.println("Buffer empty");
         }
         else if (!input.equals("O")) {   
            q.offer(input);
            System.out.println(q);
         }
         else if (q.peek() != null && input.equals("O")) {
            System.out.print("Data: ");
            System.out.printf("%s ", q.peek());
            q.poll();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(q);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I/O is as follows:

```
line1
[line1]
line2
[line1, line2]
line3
[line1, line2, line3]
O
Data: line1 
[line2, line3]
O
Data: line2 
[line3]
line1
[line1, line3]
```

the last line is my issue, it puts line1 in front of line3.
thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Read the javadoc of [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method `iterator()` is *not* guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.

`println(q)` calls `toString()` as inherited from `AbstractCollection`, which uses `iterator()`, so printing the queue will list elements in arbitrary order.

*Polling* is ordered. Iteration is not.

Comment: I don't actually want it to sort though, I want my items to be appended in order of appearance. my apologies if I am misunderstanding

Comment: If you simply want *all* elements in order of appearance, including when polling, then use a regular queue, e.g. `ArrayDeque`.

Answer (score 1):

> so i should sort it before peeking and polling?

No it is not at all necessary or needed to sort before peek/poll. It will always return the right item from the PriorityQueue.

Referring to Oracle jdk source code, the `toString()` method of the `PriorityQueue` internally uses `iterator()` method to print the contents of `PriorityQueue`. As @Andreas indicated,

> since iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order you are seeing the order that is different from what you see if you call peek/poll method.